# How I can write only one query with PDO and 2 MySQL databases

Tags: php, pdo

I have a request that I should do the joint of 2 tables, 2 tables belong to different databases, how to prepare, execute and display the results, knowing that the first connection is $db1 and 2nd is $db, and preparation is made for example,here is my code:

```
 $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service','root','');
$db1=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service1','root','');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2 ... WHERE ... id = ?';
```

Comment: Thanks, but how i can write a prepare request, here my code :                                       $sql = $db1->prepare('update myusers a inner join "'.$db.'".myusers b on (a.ID=b.ID) set a.fid=b.fid where a.ID = 1 and b.ID = 1');
   $sql->execute();

Comment: Just write it usual way.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, sorry can you exlain to me more.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference from a regular prepared statement.

Comment: thanks, it's resolved.